# How to change the tile url in react-leaflet maps

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am working on react-leaflet maps and I want to proxy the tile URL request. please help me with this like how can I override the current URL and change it to my proxy URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify react-leaflet [code example](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/simple.js) to the code below i.e. add 'const proxy' "as you can embed any JavaScript expression in JSX by wrapping it in curly braces" [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), this worked for me:

```
render() {
const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
const proxy = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
return (
  <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
    <TileLayer
    attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a>; contributors"
    url= {proxy}
    />
```